# MySQL Field Names have a Space after Import

Tags: mysql

I'm wondering if anyone knows how I can remove the spaces in a SELECT query where the field names have a space. I ran an import of a CSV file and some of the field names look like this.

" name", " type" etc.

I tried to do:

```
SELECT trim(*) FROM table_name
```

but it returned a mysql error. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: MySQL uses backtick quoted identifiers.  `SELECT \` name\` FROM table_name`

Answer (score 1):

Try backticks?  If I understand correctly, the column names have spaces and you wish to select the columns without the spaces in the name?

```
SELECT ` name` as name, ` type` as type FROM table_name
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without going that route? The problem is I do this every year for a program I made for my taxes and for 2010 and 2011, I never had this problem after importing a CSV.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski fixed, wasn't paying attention.

Comment: @SamOh No - you should really _fix the import data_ so it doesn't result in these column names.

Comment: Okay. If that's hte only way, I'll go with that. Thanks!